# Combining Nginx location blocks.

Tags: regex, nginx

I have the following config in nginx conf

```
location /request1 {
          proxy_pass  http://hostname:port/request1;
          proxy_set_header Host      $host;
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}

location /request2 {
          proxy_pass  http://hostname:port/request2;
          proxy_set_header Host      $host;
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}

location /request3 {
          proxy_pass  http://hostname:port/request3;
          proxy_set_header Host      $host;
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
```

I want to merge them into one config like

```
location ~ /(request1|request2|request3)/ {
          proxy_pass  http://hostname:port/$1;
          proxy_set_header Host      $host;
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
```

I could not figure out the syntax. Anyone can help me out?

**Answer to my question:**

The following works for me:

```
location ~ ^/(request1|request2|request3) {
    proxy_pass  http://hostname:port;
    proxy_set_header Host      $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
```

Comment: actually your configuration should work at this state as it is, what problem are you getting ?

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the last `/` from the matching. Also, add a `^` to make sure to start matching from the beginning of the uri.

```
location ~ ^/(request1|request2|request3) {
```

Comment: The trailing `/` is so that something like `/request11` for example doesn't get matched.